# Finding 3D indices of all matching values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D int64 Numpy array, which is output from skimage.measure.label. I need a list of 3D indices that match each of our possible (previously known) values, separated out by which indices correspond to each value.

Currently, we do this by the following idiom:

```
    for cur_idx,count in values_counts.items():
        region=labels[:,:,:] == cur_idx
        [dim1_indices,dim2_indices,dim3_indices]= np.nonzero(region)
```

While this code works and produces correct output, it is quite slow, especially the np.nonzero part, as we call this 200+ times on a large array. I realize that there is probably a faster way to do this via, say, numba, but we'd like to avoid adding on additional requirements unless needed.

Ultimately, what we're looking for is a list of indices that correspond to each (nonzero) value relatively efficiently. Assume our number of values <1000 but our array size >100x1000x1000. So, for example, on the array created by the following:

```
x = np.zeros((4,4,4))
x[3,3,3] = 1; x[1,0,3] = 2; x[1,2,3] = 2
```

we would want some `idx_value` dict/array such that `idx_value_1[2] = 1` `idx_value_2[2] = 2`, `idx_value_3[2] = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried tackling problems similar to the one you describe, and I think the `np.argwhere` function is probably your best option for reducing runtime (see docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)). See the code example below for how this could be used per the constraints you identify above.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((4,4,4))
x[3,3,3] = 1; x[1,0,3] = 2; x[1,2,3] = 3

# Instantiate dictionary/array to store indices
idx_value = {}

# Get indices equal to 2
idx_value[3] = np.argwhere(x == 3)
idx_value[2] = np.argwhere(x == 2)
idx_value[1] = np.argwhere(x == 1)

# Display idx_value - consistent with indices we set before
>>> idx_value
{3: array([[1, 2, 3]]), 2: array([[1, 0, 3]]), 1: array([[3, 3, 3]])}
```

For the first use case, I think you would still have to use a for loop to iterate over the values you're searching over, but it could be done as:

```
# Instantiate dictionary/array
idx_value = {}

# Now loop by incrementally adding key/value pairs
for cur_idx,count in values_counts.items():
        idx_value[cur_idx] = np.argwhere(labels)
```

**NOTE**: This incrementally creates a dictionary where each key is an `idx` to search for, and each value is a `np.array` object of shape `(N_matches, 3)`.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. The code works, but it ends up being slower than the original code. I think the issue is that, while looping over the big array by `len(values_counts)` times should be equivalent to looping over `values_counts` at each array position, the big array doesn't fit in cache (whereas `values_counts` does). That means that I need to figure out a paradigm where it loops through the array, and at each position, it checks for all values.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried a numba implementation of what I describe in the previous comment and it is somehow substantially slower.

Comment: Okay, I cleaned up my Numba implementation and I was able to speed it up by about 2-3x what it was using either our original implementation or what you suggest above. I suppose Numba will just have to be a soft requirement.